# How to convert 2 to "10" in python

Tags: python

I need to convert the string "2" to the string "10" in binary, I'm using bitarray.

```
from bitarray import bitarray
a=bitarray()
a.fromstring("2")
print(a)
```

What appears for console is `bitarray('00110010')`, I just want that only appears "10".

There is any way of doing this with Bitarray or I have to use another library?

Comment: `format(int('2'),'b')`

Comment: your result (00110010) is the ASCII encoding of the *string* 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `bitarray` library, but it seems `fromstring` stores the ASCII bits of a string into the bit array.

`format(int('2'),'b')` will do what you want. `'b'` is the format code for binary, and will return `'10'`.

Comment: That works, could do you tell me hot to invert, if a have "10" how to obtain 2 again?

Comment: `int('10',2)` -> `2`.  The second optional parameter of `int` is the base to interpret the string.

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply

```
bin(int('2'))[2:]
```

?